# No recibo los datos de un formulario en mi $_POST

Tags: php, mysql

estoy intentando crear un formulario de un curso, pero al dar click en Acceder (inicio de sesion), solo recibo lo que esta en , no lo que se escribio en el formulario.

index.php (formulario)

```
<form class="sign-box" action="" method="POST" id="login_form">
                    <div class="sign-avatar">
                        <img src="public/img/avatar-sign.png" alt="">
                    </div>
                    <header class="sign-title">Acceso</header>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" id="usu_correo" nombre="usu_correo" class="form-control" placeholder="E-Mail"/>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="password" id="usu_pass" nombre="usu_pass" class="form-control" placeholder="Password"/>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="float-right reset">
                            <a href="reset-password.html">Cambiar contraseña</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <input type="hidden" name="enviar" class="form-control" value="si">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-rounded">Acceder</button>
                </form>
```

Lo siguiente igual esta en index.php

```
   require_once("config/conexion.php");
   if(isset($_POST["enviar"]) and $_POST["enviar"]=="si"){
       require_once("models/Usuario.php");
       $usuario = new Usuario();
       $usuario->login();
      }
?>
```

Y en Usuario.php es donde tendria que recibir la informacion, pero no recibo la informacion que envio desde el formulario, que es el usu_correo y usu_pass.

```
if(isset($_POST["enviar"])){
                $correo = $_POST["usu_correo"];
                $pass = $_POST["usu_pass"];

                

                if(empty($correo) and empty($pass)){
                    header("location:".Conectar::ruta()."index.php?m=2");
                    exit();
                }else{
```

Lo unico que recibo es: {"enviar":"si"} con die(json_encode($_POST));

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema se debe a que tienes mal puesto el atributo para identificar las variables. En tu caso definiste `nombre="usu_pass"` cuando en realidad debiera ser `name="usu_pass"`.

La observación aplica para todos los campos de tu formulario.

Cuando no hay un atributo `name="something"` definido, ese input no será procesado (Según la especificación de W3C)

Comment: Ya se resolvió con lo que mencionas, agradezco tu ayuda.